# NoSql document structure

Tags: mongodb

I have a database of 3 tables:
Brands (think MacDonalds) -> shops -> sales

Each shop has many sales and each brand has many shops. If I want to query how many sales McDonalds has in order to build a report how do I structure my brands document? Do I keep a `sales` field in the brands document which gets updated whenever each shop makes a sale or I keep a `sale` field in the shops document and then I loop through all the shops to create a SUM of sales for each brand.

First approach will probably behave better on reads while the second on writes. My database will have more reads than writes (at least at start) so I'm interested to find out what's the standard way of doing this in MongoDB especially.

Coming from a relational DB I would probably have Shops -> BrandShops -> Shop -> Sales etc but I'm just trying out Mongo. Thanks.

Comment: Is `sales` just a number (per brand)? Or a document for every sale made? Is `shops`:`brand` many-to-many ?

Comment: Yes `sales` is a counter of how many sales a brand has. Each shop should also have `sales` field if the admin digs deeper. `brand`:`shops` is one to many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a one-to-many relation in MongoDB, it is usually preferable to embed the data in the owning object instead of representing the relation with database references. The reason is that MongoDB doesn't support joins - when you need data from two different collections, you need to query both collections separately.

When you have a many-to-many relationship, you should use arrays of references instead of embedding, because otherwise you would have to update all the objects which embed an object which changed.

But note that there is a 16MB limit per document in MongoDB. When the object with embedded objects could get close to this limit, you should still use references (either in form of an array in the owning object, or a field in the owned object).

References in MongoDB can be either object IDs, [DBRef's](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/database-references/) (which many drivers can resolve automatically or semi-automatically) or a custom unique identifier like a name or an ID number. The latter has the advantage that you can show the user a meaningful overview list of the related documents without querying them all. Needless to say, that this field should have an unique index in the referenced collection. You can also combine the reference with some essential data points of the referenced object to be able to present a more meaningful preview to the user.